# change connection db to PDO

Tags: php, pdo

i have recently code change database connection to PDO.
actually i have do it right and success. but i want a little modification in pdo connection. 
this is the old code:

```
$sql = "select * from pengguna where marketing = '$nim_temp'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {                               
        $marketing= $row['marketing'];
        $password = $row['password'];                               
        $akses= $row['akses'];
    }
}
```

and my new code using PDO:

```
$sql = "select * from pengguna where marketing = :nim_temp";    
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':nim_temp'=>$nim_temp));
$result=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

if($result)
{
    while($row = $result)
    {                       
        //echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$row['marketing'].'");</script>';
        $marketing= $row['marketing'];
        $password = $row['password'];                               
        $akses= $row['akses'];
    }
}
```

It is success without $result and if result like:

```
//$result=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
//if($result){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ))
```

what i want is, i still need `if($result)` to trigger my other code.

Comment: sorry, i think that's not duplicate. the basic is same using PDO, BUT i am **focus on checking with $result**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your query was a success or not is now determined by `execute()`, not by `fetch()`. So you have to do it like this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':nim_temp'=>$nim_temp));

if($result)
{
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: that's really helpfull. thanks a lot. all my code work well include insert, edit and download in one page. once again thanks.